# How to get the mobile and desktop API path in page speed insights?

Tags: json, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Hi i just want to ask if there's seperated API in pagespeed insight in performance score? Because i only seeing this path to consume in performance score and i don't know if it's for desktop or mobile

```
lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine the strategy from result, we can refer to `lighthouseResult.emulatedFormFactor`

By default it runs for DESKTOP.
To make it run for MOBILE, there exists a query param [`strategy`](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#strategy)

Here's sample request for strategy=MOBILE

```
curl \
  'https://pagespeedonline.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&strategy=MOBILE&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Reference: [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%22%2C%22strategy%22%3A%22MOBILE%22%7D)